# Plotting time durations

Tags: r, lattice, lubridate

Some of my data consists of duration values expressed in seconds. I'm using the `Duration` data type from the `lubridate` package.

To plot this data I'm calling `barchart()` from the `lattice` package. The issue is that the values are displayed back in seconds. Is there any way I can control how the axis labels get formatted?

This figure shows what I'm getting right now:

[image: Current]

... which I'm generating using:

```
barchart(val1 ~ val2, groups=group, mydata, 
         auto.key=list(
           columns=1, 
           space="right", 
           text=c("Pilot 1","Pilot 2")
           ), 
         main="Title",
         xlab="Tasks", ylab="Duration"
)
```

Instead, I'd like to have something closer to this (in what the y axis labels is concerned):

[image: Intended]

---

**Update:** Adding some sample csv data:

```
group,val2,val1
pilot01,t1,429.226015
pilot01,t3,693.795607
pilot02,t1,262.798468
pilot02,t3,325.854107
```

Comment: Are you looking for only `lattice` solution (or `ggplot2` is alright as well)?

Comment: I'm using ``lattice`` because I could easily get it to group the bars like the examples shown above. But I suppose ``ggplot2`` is also a good option if it allows me to do the same.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: Sure. I've updated the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Lattice the `scales` arguments control the axis; Probably something along the lines of this untested code:

```
  ..., scales=list(y=list(at=seq.POSIXt(0, 700, length= 6), 
                          labels=format(seq.POSIXt(0, 700, length= 6), "%H:%M:%S:)
                   ), ...
```

To get this in tested form I needed to convert the seconds to POSIXt format:

```
mydata$val1time <- as.POSIXct(mydata$val1, origin="1970-01-01")
barchart(val1time ~ val2, groups=group, mydata, horizontal=FALSE, 
         scales=list( y=list( 
            at=seq.POSIXt(from=as.POSIXct(0, origin="1970-01-01"), 
                          to=as.POSIXct(700, origin="1970-01-01"), length= 12), 
            labels=format( seq.POSIXt(from=as.POSIXct(0, origin="1970-01-01"), 
                    to=as.POSIXct(720, origin="1970-01-01"), length= 12), "%H:%M:%S")
                     )   ), 
       auto.key=list(
           columns=1, 
           space="right", 
           text=c("Pilot 1","Pilot 2")
           ), 
         main="Title", xlab="Tasks", ylab="Duration"
)
```

[image]

And if you needed it to go from 0 upwards you would need to add:

```
 ..., ylim=range( as.numeric( seq.POSIXt(from=as.POSIXct(0, origin="1970-01-01"), 
                                    to=as.POSIXct(700, origin="1970-01-01"),
                                    length= 12))) ,
```

For the purposes of showing that an entire set of commands give that result (with the addition of the 'ylim' argument, I am pasting the code I used with the dataframe name `dat`:

```
 dat <- read.table(text="group,val2,val1
 pilot01,t1,429.226015
 pilot01,t3,693.795607
 pilot02,t1,262.798468
 pilot02,t3,325.854107", header=TRUE, sep=",")
dat$val1time <- as.POSIXct(dat$val1, origin="1970-01-01")

barchart(val1time ~ val2, groups=group, dat, horizontal=FALSE, 
          scales=list( y=list( at=seq.POSIXt(from=as.POSIXct(0, origin="1970-01-01"), to=as.POSIXct(700, origin="1970-01-01"), length= 12), 
                              labels=format( seq.POSIXt(from=as.POSIXct(0, origin="1970-01-01"), to=as.POSIXct(720, origin="1970-01-01"), length= 12), "%H:%M:%S")
                      )   ), 
        auto.key=list(
            columns=1, 
            space="right", 
            text=c("Pilot 1","Pilot 2")
            ), 
          main="Title", xlab="Tasks", ylab="Duration"
 , ylim=range( as.numeric( seq.POSIXt(from=as.POSIXct(0, origin="1970-01-01"), 
                                    to=as.POSIXct(700, origin="1970-01-01"),
                                    length= 12))))
```

Comment: Thanks. There's one think not quite working yet. This line is making the bars horizontal instead of vertical: ``mydata$val1time <- as.POSIXct(mydata$val1, origin="1970-01-01")``. This should just be adding a new column to ``mydata``, right?

Comment: Btw, ``mydata`` is a ``frame`` (not sure if it's important, but suspect that it is).

Comment: I assumed it was a dataframe and although at one point I was having similar puzzlement about why I was getting a horizontal plot, I no longer see that problem.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer, as your example obviously works well. Something is missing me when I try to adapt it to my slightly more complex use case (still get those horizontal bars), but I will have to come back to this later. Thanks.